# Yet another MySQL pivot table question - is it a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, specific-question

One of the regularly recurring questions in the MySQL space is how to create pivot tables by transposing data in rows to columns.

In the past years quite a few excellent answers have been provided, describing both static and dynamic pivoting in MySQL.

Today yet another question has been asked in this space: *[Create columns from the value rows in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46961442/create-columns-from-the-value-rows-in-mysql)*

I closed it down as duplicate, linking it to the following question: *[MySQL - Rows to Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241178/mysql-rows-to-columns)*.

The most upvoted answer provide a step-by-step description on how to create such pivot tables within MySQL. Even the 2nd most updated answer provides a simple code producing the expected results.

Another high-rep user removed the duplicate closure and provided an answer - repeating the same logic described in the answers I linked as duplicate.

The same high-rep user has provided the same pivoting logic to a number of questions already, so could have chosen an alternative dupe target from his own range of answers. Examples:

- *[Aggregate rows to create new columns based off row content in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45886305/mysql-aggregate-rows-to-create-new-columns-based-off-row-content)*
- *[SQL: transform rows into columns in MySQL (SELECT statement)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28066983/sql-transform-rows-into-columns-in-mysql-select-statement)*

My question:

Is the *[Create columns from the value rows in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46961442/create-columns-from-the-value-rows-in-mysql)* question a duplicate of [MySQL - Rows to Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241178/mysql-rows-to-columns)?

Update: In the meantime a third high-rep user closed down the question as a duplicate, but I'm still interested in the community's opinion regarding this question.

Comment: The simple answer is - yes it is a duplicate.